# Initializing Unique Pointers as a Class Member

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I am working on a tree structure that has a vector of `unique pointers` as a class member. While working on it, I realised that I am not sure how to initialize a unique pointer as a class member if the object, which the unique pointer will own, comes as a parameter.

So, I am simply asking: How I should initialize unique pointers as a class member if the object that will be owned comes as a parameter?

Should I use new ( `addTheObject(new Object())` ) and then use `std::make_unique`? Should I pass the object as unique_ptr ( `addTheObject(std::unique_ptr<Object>& theObject)` ) and use `std::move(theObject)`?

What is the correct way to handle this?

In case you need more concrete example:

I have a `DT_Node` class, which is a node of a tree, and I will construct a tree using `DT_Node`.

`DT_Node` has a method called `addChild()` that is used to insert children into its node vector.

`DT_Node` will be used in different cpp files to construct a tree, which means another cpp file will use `addChild()` method to add the children of the node.

```
// DT_Node.hpp
class DT_Node
{
public:

    DT_Node();
    virtual ~DT_Node();

    virtual void decide() = 0;

    virtual void addChild( ??? );

private:

    std::vector< std::unique_ptr<DT_Node> > mNodes;
};
```

---

```
// DT_Node.cpp
DT_Node::DT_Node()
{

}

DT_Node::~DT_Node()
{
    mNodes.clear();
}

void DT_Node::addChild( ??? )
{
    ???
}
```

Comment: *"comes as a parameter."* - what do you mean?  Your class is not a template with parameters, nor does the constructor shown have function arguments...?

Comment: Yeah, I meant function parameters or arguments

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need is:

```
void DT::Node::addChild(std::unique_ptr<DT_Node>&& child) {
    mNodes.emplace_back(std::move(child));
}
```

By the way, your title is misleading.  The unique_ptr is not a member (it is contained in a member), and you are not definitely not initializing a member (for which you would use the member initializer list syntax in the constructor).

Comment: Sorry about the title, my motivation is trying to make the question generic

Answer (score 3):

`std::unique_ptr` keeps the *own* of the pointed object. That means if you want to pass it as a parameter, you have to *move* the ownership.

Something like (note the `move` and `&&`-reference):

```
void addChild(std::unique_ptr<Node>&& iNode) {
  mNodes.emplace_back(std::move(iNode));
}
```

Finally, I'd strongly suggest you take a look at [this Herb Sutter Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE&t=3663s).
It gives some useful advice on data structures with smart pointers.

Comment: Note that the OP's member variable was called `mNodes`, not `_nodes`.    The first sentence is the critical one that is missing from my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the video!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that DT_Node is not a pure virtual base class , this is the code snippet. You will need a copy constructor as well. Two versions of the addChild is used which is self explanatory.

```
  class DT_Node
{
public:    
    DT_Node();
    DT_Node(const DT_Node& other); // copy constructor will be needed
    virtual void addChild(std::unique_ptr<DT_Node>&& node); // move from source
    virtual void addChild(const std::unique_ptr<DT_Node>& node);  //non destructible source

private:    
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DT_Node> > mNodes;
};    

void DT_Node::addChild(std::unique_ptr<DT_Node>&& node) 
{
    mNodes.push_back(std::move(node));
}
void DT_Node::addChild(const std::unique_ptr<DT_Node>& node)  
{

    std::unique_ptr<DT_Node> new_node = std::make_unique<DT_Node>(*node);
    mNodes.push_back(std::move(new_node));
}
```

Comment: The second implementation of `addChild` will end up with two `unique_ptrs` owning the same object, and UB when the second of them tries to delete it.  You *could* use `node.release()`, but that is definitely not a const member.

Comment: Ah. No.  I see.  It is invoking the copy constructor.  That code is definitely *not* self explanatory.  It desperately needs a comment.

Comment: @MartinBonner: Yes, the second function will enable creating a new node without destroying the parent-node which is required in some search trees